# Error in sqoop incremental import command

Tags: hadoop, sqoop

Im working on a sqoop incremental import command. But Im getting error message in the end which I couldn't understand where is the problem.
Below is my MySQL table data

```
+----+-----------+
| ID | NAME      |
+----+-----------+
|  1 | Sidhartha |
|  2 | Sunny     |
|  3 | Saketh    |
|  4 | Bobby     |
|  5 | Yash      |
|  6 | Nimmi     |
+----+-----------+
```

Hive table with 4 records: DAY is the partitioned column

```
importedtable.id    importedtable.name  importedtable.day
1   Sidhartha   1
2   Sunny   1
3   Saketh  1
4   Bobby   1
```

My Sqoop command:

```
sqoop import --connect jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1/mydb --table MYTAB --driver com.mysql.jdbc.Driver --username root --password cloudera --hive-import --hive-table importedtable --incremental append --check-column id --last-value $(hive -e "select max(id) from importedtable") --target-dir '/home/incdata';
```

Error message:

```
17/03/08 12:15:14 ERROR tool.BaseSqoopTool: Error parsing arguments for import:
17/03/08 12:15:14 ERROR tool.BaseSqoopTool: Unrecognized argument: WARN:
17/03/08 12:15:14 ERROR tool.BaseSqoopTool: Unrecognized argument: The
17/03/08 12:15:14 ERROR tool.BaseSqoopTool: Unrecognized argument: method
17/03/08 12:15:14 ERROR tool.BaseSqoopTool: Unrecognized argument: class
17/03/08 12:15:14 ERROR tool.BaseSqoopTool: Unrecognized argument: org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SLF4JLogFactory#release()
17/03/08 12:15:14 ERROR tool.BaseSqoopTool: Unrecognized argument: was
17/03/08 12:15:14 ERROR tool.BaseSqoopTool: Unrecognized argument: invoked.
17/03/08 12:15:14 ERROR tool.BaseSqoopTool: Unrecognized argument: WARN:
17/03/08 12:15:14 ERROR tool.BaseSqoopTool: Unrecognized argument: Please
17/03/08 12:15:14 ERROR tool.BaseSqoopTool: Unrecognized argument: see
17/03/08 12:15:14 ERROR tool.BaseSqoopTool: Unrecognized argument: http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#release
17/03/08 12:15:14 ERROR tool.BaseSqoopTool: Unrecognized argument: for
17/03/08 12:15:14 ERROR tool.BaseSqoopTool: Unrecognized argument: an
17/03/08 12:15:14 ERROR tool.BaseSqoopTool: Unrecognized argument: explanation.
17/03/08 12:15:14 ERROR tool.BaseSqoopTool: Unrecognized argument: --target-dir
17/03/08 12:15:14 ERROR tool.BaseSqoopTool: Unrecognized argument: /home/incdata
```

Can anyone tell me what is the mistake Im doing the sqoop command.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the hive query passed as the value for `--last-value` argument,

```
--last-value $(hive -e "select max(id) from importedtable")
```

This emits the log messages along with the result to `--last-value`.

Use `-S` (--silent) flag to the query,

```
--last-value $(hive -S -e "select max(id) from importedtable")
```

Comment: @frankin, still getting the same error with '-S' in the --last-value

Comment: Please check the updated answer, `-S` is part of hive execution.

Comment: Executed the command same as you gave(the updated answer). It is still not working. 17/03/08 12:49:47 ERROR tool.BaseSqoopTool: Error parsing arguments for import:
Unrecognized argument: WARN:
The method class org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SLF4JLogFactory#release() was invoked.
Please see http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#release for an explanation.

Comment: This log warning is emitted from hive which should have been suppressed by `-S` flag. Did you execute the hive statement alone in the terminal? and what is the result?

Comment: Yes I did. This is the result of that particular statement you are asking.
2017-03-08 12:55:11,550 WARN  [main] mapreduce.TableMapReduceUtil: The hbase-prefix-tree module jar containing PrefixTreeCodec is not present.  Continuing without it.
4
WARN: The method class org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SLF4JLogFactory#release() was invoked.
WARN: Please see http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#release for an explanation.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137524/discussion-between-sidhartha-and-franklinsijo).

Comment: As you said, -S is to suppress the logs. But it looks like I made some logical mistake in the command. I don't understand the usage of -S here.

Comment: The query `select max(id) from importedtable;` when executed with `hive -e` will stdout the mapreduce logs. To silent this stdout `-S` flag is passed additionally. Check the chat link for example!